# Mongoid: fetch rows through Hash

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have got field in my Mongo table that is stored as a Hash.

```
"values" : {
    "4e64b7cb3e9b3a4d8a00000b" : "Page",
    "4e77304b3e9b3a4ace000003" : "Michael",
    "4e64b7cb3e9b3a4d8a00000c" : 6,
    "4e64b7cb3e9b3a4d8a00000d" : 4,
    "4e64b7cb3e9b3a4d8a00000e" : 2,
    "4e64b7cb3e9b3a4d8a00000f" : 6,
    "4e64b7cb3e9b3a4d8a000010" : 12
}
```

Now I need to fetch all rows where `values` stores data equal to `Michael`

Like in Ruby:

```
Table.all.select{|row| row.values.any?{|k,v| v == 'Michael' }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [use multikeys to simulate a large number of indexes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Using+Multikeys+to+Simulate+a+Large+Number+of+Indexes) which makes such key/value queries more efficient. `values` should be an array, however, rather than a complex object with unknown schema, because that rules out indexing by definition.

```
SomeCollection
{
  values : [
      { "key" : "4e64b7cb3e9b3a4d8a00000b", "value" : "Page" },
      { "key" : "4e77304b3e9b3a4ace000003", "value" : "Michael" },
      /* ... */
  ]
}

db.SomeCollection.ensureIndex("values");

db.foo.find( { values : {value: 'Michael'} } )
```

Because of the way MongoDB works with arrays, this will find all documents that have at least one element in `values` with `value` "Michael". Note, however, that this will find the parent document, not the key/value pair itself.

Comment: Good approach! Thanx! But now I have got many logic connected with `"4e64b7cb3e9b3a4d8a00000b" : "Page"` this kind of storing data (it should be refactored). So maybe I can make this kind of fetching without refactoring all the code and scheme?

Comment: Yes, you can reach into the object just like any other - but it **won't use an index, so it will be slow**: `db.foo.find({"values.4e64b7cb3e9b3a4d8a00000b" : "Page"})`.

Comment: `4e64b7cb3e9b3a4d8a00000b` is dynamic token :)

Comment: Why would you store a large object in the database which is not of any relevance for querying *or* as a result? In that case, you'll have to refactor I'm afraid.

Comment: There wasn't any need in quering till now :). Thank you